# Serializing nested object private fields

Tags: php, symfony, serialization, jmsserializerbundle

I've got one **Aggregate root - Product** - that has few fields and some of them are objects, like Price. It looks like that ( of course it is simplified ):

```
Product
{
    private $price;

    public function __construct(Price $price)
    {
       $this->price = $price;
    }
}


Price
{

    private $currency;
    private $amount;

    public function __construct($currency, $amount)
    {
       $this->currency = $currency;
       $this->amount= $amount;
    }
}
```

**This aggregate root doesn't contain "getPrice" method**, it's not needed in Domain.

The issue:
I need to serialize this aggregate, but I would like to have it in this format:

Product.json

```
{    
    "priceCurrency": "GBP",
    "priceAmount": 100 
}
```

I've been trying with JMSSerializer, but can't really get it from config. This for example **doesn't work**:

**Product.yml**

```
Namespace\Product:
   virtual_properties:
     getAmount:
         exp: object.price.amount
         serialized_name: priceAmount
         type: integer
     getCurrency:
         exp: object.price.currency
         serialized_name: priceCurrency
         type: string
```

I understand that it's due to the fact, that "exp" part is being used by Symfony Expression Language and from what I know it doesn't support getting values from private fields in any other way then through theirs methods. I also know that JMSSerializer itself supports that. I don't have to have field "getPrice" to serialize "price" field.

**Question**: Is there any way to achieve what I want just through config or do I have to write listeners on post_serialize event?

Comment: Why are you using a virtual property and not just setting the `serialized_name` on the property itself?

Comment: hmm? How that would help me? serialized_name is just the name of the serialized field, and I have trouble with getting value, not setting the name.

Comment: Maybe I was misunderstanding what the issue was...I thought JMS just used reflection to get private field values.  Is that what you're having trouble with?  Or is it the fact that you're trying to get a particular value from an associated object?

Answer (score 1):

Use something like this:

```
<?php

class Property
{
    protected $reflection;
    protected $obj;

    public function __construct($obj)
    {
        $this->obj = $obj;
        $this->reflection = new ReflectionObject($obj);
    }

    public function set($name, $value)
    {
        $this->getProperty($name)->setValue($this->obj, $value);
    }

    public function get($name)
    {
        return $this->getProperty($name)->getValue($this->obj);
    }

    protected function getProperty($name)
    {
        $property = $this->reflection->getProperty($name);
        $property->setAccessible(true);
        return $property;
    }
}

// example
class Foo
{
    protected $bar = 123;

    public function getBar()
    {
        return $this->bar;
    }
}

$foo = new Foo();
echo 'original: '.$foo->getBar().PHP_EOL;

$prop = new Property($foo);
echo 'reflection - before changes: '.$prop->get('bar').PHP_EOL;

$prop->set('bar', 'abc');

echo 'after changes: '.$foo->getBar().PHP_EOL;
```